# How do I replace the formula in a cell with the output of the formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

How do I replace the formula in a cell with the output of the formula?

I simply need "=RIGHT(E86,LEN(E86)+1-FIND("(",E86,1))" to become "(e)"

Is there a way to do this to the whole sheet? Replace all the cells with formulas with the text they are displaying? I am using version 2003.

Answer (score 8):

Select the cells you want to replace and copy them.  Then go to "Edit->Paste Special" and select values instead of all.

Since this doesn't change non-formula cells, you could select the entire sheet and  copy->paste special to remove all formulas.

To do it programatically, look at Steve's answer.  He's got the code you'll need.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was a simple way to do it. This is what happens when you are unemployed for too long. You start to forget simple things you used for work.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively something like the following will work if you want to avoid using the clipboard

```
Dim r as range
For each r in Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Cells
   r.Value = r.Value
Next
```

I haven't excel to hand I'm afraid so you'll need to check the syntax.

Comment: I just checked using Excel and that is exactly correct except for capitalization, which it will fix automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it: double-click the cell in question and press F9.